# Using Brown in c++ Console

Tags: c++, windows, console, windows-xp

I am creating an ASCII based c++ game using Windows XP Console. I am working on coloring the text and background for the game using SetConsoleTextAttribute. I have bee able to get most of the colors I want, but one color I can't get quite right is brown. The only suggestions I have been able to find have listed using 6 as the value for foreground (SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (6))) Is what I have been using. This, however, comes out as a Tan Brown, more of a dirty yellow than anything. Is there any way to get true brown using this function? If not, what other options do I have to get brown in Console Ascii? Like I said, I have found many pages saying to use 6 or FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUDN_GREEN, but that's not really brown. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the fault of the terminal settings. It gets to decide what color each ANSI value means. There's not much you can do from inside a basic console program unless you have a 256-color terminal.

Comment: In order to have more control over the console colors, you will need to use a library (e.g. curses) that has those abilities.  The Windows console does not have a published API for that functionality.

Comment: The colors available in the console are basically the bare minimum that could be guaranteed with the hardware available over 20 years ago. Microsoft never had any incentive to improve it as they preferred you use the Windows interface instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Over 20 years ago, that puke yellow color was exactly the brown I think Evanias wanted :P \*misses VGA colors\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fault of the terminal settings. It gets to decide what color each ANSI value means. There's not much you can do from inside a basic console program unless you have a 256-color terminal.

There's probably a way to change the terminal's settings using various windows APIs (registry settings? ui automation or something?) but that's a whole other can of fish which I'll defer to windows programmers.

For your own purposes, you can just go into the terminal settings and change the puke yellow color to the brown you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll see if that will meet my needs! Thanks!